# How to load and print json array/object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, d3.js, load

I do not have any json and d3 knowledge (just started to read few hours back) but have very basic javascript knowledge. I have to load a json file and print all the array and objects on the console using d3. I was wondering if anyone can help me to solve it. Actually, I did it but does not work :(
My json file.

```
 {
    "addressfile": "info", 
        "struct": {
          "address": [
               [
                  "A", 
                  "B", 
               ], 
               [
                  "B", 
                  "C", 
               ], 
         ], 

           "address1": {
           "address2": {
           "address3": {
                  "zip": [
                      "NUMBER", 
                        0
                     ]
                  }, 
            "address_type": "Home"
            }, 
         }
     }, 
    "COUNTRY": {}, 
    }
```

My javascript code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
<body>
<script>
//LOADING JSON FILE
d3.json("address.json", function(error, root) {
      if (error) return console.error(error);
          for (var p in location) if (location.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
               console.log(p + " : " + location[p]);
           }
       }
 </script>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Please help me to solve it...

Comment: Should that be `location` instead of `root` as the second argument to the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
d3.json("appinfo.json", function(location) {
```

I know the docs say the callback takes two parameters, in a project I recently did with d3 version 3.4.13, the callback function would only work if I only passed it the data parameter.

Answer (score 0):

your code missing a closing parenthesis - );

correct code would be :

```
<script>
    d3.json("appinfo.json", function(error, root) {
         if (error) return console.error(error);

          console.log(root) // output -your JSON data as pojo

          //for (var p in location) if (location.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
          //     console.log(p + " : " + location[p]);
          //}
    });
</script>
```

- make sure you write correct url to your json file in first parameter to d3.json().
- make sure that appinfo.json contain correct json object, you can test it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the fix :D, but still it does not work. Json path is correct(i also hard coded it) and the format is a valid json file.. any other ideas :(....

Comment: yes.. I got this in the console...                                               mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create 
Object { sourcefile: "Script", structure: Object, components: Object, node_mapping: Object } 
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: do you see the request with expected response in network tab of developer tools ?

Comment: It was showing :                                                     In Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load the json file (but when I click on the same link it works) In Firefox: I am not getting such error but no display...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.. After struggling I got the solution..
Solution: External Json files are not supported by the browsers ..so I needed to use webserver. Then I was able to see the output of it in the console.
the final code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <head>
   <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <script>
        d3.json("address.json", function(location) {
        console.log(location)
  });
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Hope it might help others to solve in minutes not in hours like me.....